# Degrees of Freedom contributing to dynamic?

Tags: thermodynamics, molecules, degrees-of-freedom, chemical-compounds

I had a question regarding considering how many degrees of freedom (dof), contributing to dynamics, a $\rm CCl_4$ Molecule has.
In General there are 5 Atoms in the Molecule, so the maximum would be 15, not considering the inner dof.
But what does this even mean? What are non dynamic dof´s?

Comment: Some more context would help to provide a helpful answer. The bare counting in 3D is what you did: 15. That's the number of coordinates required to specify an atomic configuration. What additional information are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The degrees of freedom for system is the number of independent parameters which can define its state.

A tetrahedral (one central atom with four tetrahedral bonds) molecule like $\text{CCl}_4$, will have $15$ degrees of freedom.

There will be $3$ translational d.o.f.s for movement in the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes.

There will be $3$ rotational d.o.f.s for rotations about the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes.

For all non-linear molecules, like $\text{CCl}_4$,there are be $(3N-6)=9$ vibrational dofs (with $N$ being the number of atoms) for the bending, stretching and twisting modes of the bonds in the molecule.

Overall, for $\text{CCl}_4$ we therefore have a total of $3+3+9=15$ d.o.f.s.

Note that for $N$ single atoms you would need $3N$ coordinates to specify each of their positions in $x$, $y$, and $z$. But for a molecule, all the atoms are attached to another, so you need $3$ coordinates to define translational motion of the whole molecule, and $3$ for whole molecule's rotation about the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes. This leaves $3N-6$ degrees of freedom to describe vibrations.

> But what does this even mean? What are non dynamic dof´s?

The "non dynamic" d.o.f.s mean non-vibrational degrees of freedom. In this case, we talk about pure translation and pure rotation. This means we have $3+3=6$ non-vibrational dofs.